# How to retain actual input newline/end-of-line (hex 0x0a) in macro definition

Tags: macros, line-breaking, definition

I am using `filecontents` package and want to include it in a macro in order to factorize some complex processing.
The problem is that `\begin{filecontents}` needs be followed by nothing except spaces and an actual trailing newline which is unfortunately absorbed by the way TeX/LaTex processes the macro definition.
Here is the M(not)WE :

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{filecontents}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\newcommand{\cf}[2]{%
% next-line-compulsorily-ends-only-with-spaces-then-newline
\begin{filecontents}{prefix-#1.tex}
factored-complex-processing-of{#2}
\end{filecontents}
}
\show\cf
%
\cf{suffix1}{somefirststuff}
%
\begin{filecontents}{prefix-suffix2.tex}
complex-processing-of{somenextstuff}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

some-package-macro-processing-using-suffix-number{1,2}

Equivalent to:

\input{prefix-suffix1.tex}
\input{prefix-suffix2.tex}

\end{document}
```

Because of the absorbed thus non-existing newline at the end of the `\begin{filecontents}` line inside the `\newcommand{\cf}`, TeX/LaTeX does not *understand* this command and processes the rest as text to be output, which causes the `Missing \begin{document}` error.

I have tried to seek wordarounds involving `\def`, `\edef`, `\noexpand`, `\catcode` and the like, but I did not find anything useful.

So is there a way to keep this actual input newline/end-of-line in the macro definition ?

Comment: Are you aware that the filecotents-environment switches to verbatim-catcode-régime for tokenizing the body of the environment and thus expects the phrase `\end{filecontents}` to be tokenized under verbatim-catcode-rǵime also, which is not the case with your `\cf`-macro as its definition, inclusive the the body of the environment and the phrase `\end{filecontents}` get tokenized under normal catcode-régime?

Comment: You don't *need* `filecontents` to write to a file. Do you want to write a single line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\newcommand\exchange[2]{#2#1}

% The integer-parameter \newlinechar usually has the value 10.
% This means if at the time of writing to text-file (La)TeX encounters a
% character whose code-point's number in (La)TeX's internal character-encoding
% (which either is ASCII or is UTF-8)  is 10, it will not write that character
% but will write a linebreak. 10 denotes the Line Feed-character and using
% (La)TeX's ^^-notation you can also write it as ^^J.

\begingroup
\newcommand\cf[2]{%
  \endgroup
  \newcommand{\cf}[2]{%
    \scantokens{%
      #1{prefix-##1.tex}^^J%
      factored-complex-processing-of{##2}^^J%
      #2%
    }%
  }%
}%
\expandafter\exchange\expandafter{\expandafter{\string\end{filecontents}}}%
{\expandafter\cf\expandafter{\string\begin{filecontents}}}%

\cf{suffix1}{ somefirststuff\LaTeX}%

\begin{filecontents}{prefix-suffix2.tex}
factored-complex-processing-of{ somenextstuff\LaTeX}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\noindent prefix-suffix1.tex is:

\verbatiminput{prefix-suffix1.tex}

\noindent\hrulefill\null

\noindent prefix-suffix2.tex is:

\verbatiminput{prefix-suffix2.tex}

\noindent\hrulefill\null

Do you see the subtle difference?

In prefix-suffix1.tex there is a space behind the phrase \verb|\LaTeX|.

In prefix-suffix2.tex there is no space behind the phrase \verb|\LaTeX|.

The reason is:

prefix-suffix1.tex comes from the \verb|\cf|-command.

The tokens forming the second argument of \verb|\cf| were
tokenized under normal catcode-r\'egime. Thus the phrase \verb|\LaTeX| got
tokenized as control-word-token. When \verb|\scantokens| did its simulated
unexpanded-writing-part, that control-word-token got written unexpanded
with a trailing space as \LaTeX{} always writes control-word-tokens with
a trailing space.\\
Besides this, hashes of catcode 6 will be doubled at writing time also.

If you don't like such side-effects, you need to have  \LaTeX{} read the
second argument of \verb|\cf| under verbatim-catcode-r\'egime. How to do
that is exhibited in the other example.

\noindent\hrulefill\null

\noindent\verb|\input{prefix-suffix1.tex}| yields:

\noindent\input{prefix-suffix1.tex}

\noindent\hrulefill\null

\noindent\verb|\input{prefix-suffix2.tex}| yields:

\noindent\input{prefix-suffix2.tex}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Be aware that `\scantokens{<stuff>}`, which is provided by the e-TeX-extensions, is similar to

```
\newtoks\myscratchtoks
\newwrite\myscratchwrite
...
\immediate\openout\myscratchwrite temp.tex\relax
\myscratchtoks{<stuff>}%
\immediate\write\myscratchwrite{\the\myscratchtoks}%
\immediate\closeout\myscratchwrite
\input temp.tex %\@@@input with LaTeX 2e.
```

I said "similar" because it is not exactly the same: `\scantokens`itself is expandable, while the code-snippet above is not.

E.g, with `\scantokens` you can do

```
\expandafter\def\expandafter\temp\scantokens{{definition text}}
```

When adapting the code-snippet above, would have to do:

```
\newtoks\myscratchtoks
\newwrite\myscratchwrite
...
\immediate\openout\myscratchwrite temp.tex\relax
\myscratchtoks{{definition text}}%
\immediate\write\myscratchwrite{\the\myscratchtoks}%
\immediate\closeout\myscratchwrite
\expandafter\def\expandafter\temp\input temp.tex %\@@@input with LaTeX 2e.
```

With both approaches unexpanded writing/simulated unexpanded writing of tokens to text-file takes place.

Be aware that when unexpanded-writing of tokens takes place, character-tokens of catcode 6 will be doubled, i.e., hashes `#` of catcode 6 will be doubled.

Be aware that when unexpanded-writing of tokens takes place, control-word-tokens will be written with a trailing space.

If you don't want these effects, you need to turn `\cf` into a macro which does read its stuff under verbatimized-catcode-conditions. **If you do this, `\cf` must not get its arguments supplied via other macros but it must get them by reading and tokenizing from the tex-input-file. I.e., the same restrictions apply as, e.g., with the `\verb`-command.**

I can offer a routine `\UDcollectverbarg`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\UD@firstofone[1]{#1}%
\newcommand\UD@firstoftwo[2]{#1}%
\newcommand\UD@secondoftwo[2]{#2}%
\newcommand\UD@exchange[2]{#2#1}%
\newcommand\UD@PassFirstToSecond[2]{#2{#1}}%
%%<-------------------- Code for \UDcollectverbarg -------------------->
%% Check whether argument is empty:
%%......................................................................
%% \UD@CheckWhetherNull{<Argument which is to be checked>}%
%%                     {<Tokens to be delivered in case that argument
%%                       which is to be checked is empty>}%
%%                     {<Tokens to be delivered in case that argument
%%                       which is to be checked is not empty>}%
%% The gist of this macro comes from Robert R. Schneck's \ifempty-macro:
%% <https://groups.google.com/forum/#!original/comp.text.tex/kuOEIQIrElc/lUg37FmhA74J>
\newcommand\UD@CheckWhetherNull[1]{%
  \romannumeral0\expandafter\UD@secondoftwo\string{\expandafter
  \UD@secondoftwo\expandafter{\expandafter{\string#1}\expandafter
  \UD@secondoftwo\string}\expandafter\UD@firstoftwo\expandafter{\expandafter
  \UD@secondoftwo\string}\expandafter\expandafter\UD@firstoftwo{ }{}%
  \UD@secondoftwo}{\expandafter\expandafter\UD@firstoftwo{ }{}\UD@firstoftwo}%
}%
%%......................................................................
\begingroup
\catcode`\^^M=12 %
\UD@firstofone{%
  \endgroup%
  \newcommand\UDEndlreplace[2]{\romannumeral0\@UDEndlreplace{#2}#1^^M\relax{}}%
  \newcommand*\@UDEndlreplace{}%
  \long\def\@UDEndlreplace#1#2^^M#3\relax#4#5{%
    \UD@CheckWhetherNull{#3}%
    { #5{#4#2}}{\@UDEndlreplace{#1}#3\relax{#4#2#1}{#5}}%
  }%
}%
\newcommand\UDcollectverbarg[3]{%
  \begingroup
  \let\do\@makeother % <- this and the next line switch to
  \dospecials        %    verbatim-category-code-régime.
  \catcode`\{=1      % <- give opening curly brace the usual catcode so a 
                     %    curly-brace-balanced argument can be gathered in
                     %    case of the first thing of the verbatimized-argument 
                     %    being a curly opening brace.
  \catcode`\ =10     % <- give space and horizontal tab the usual catcode so \UD@collectverbarg
  \catcode`\^^I=10   %    cannot catch a space or a horizontal tab as its 4th undelimited argument.
                     %    (Its 4th undelimited argument denotes the verbatim-
                     %     syntax-delimiter in case of not gathering a
                     %     curly-brace-nested argument.)
  \kernel@ifnextchar\bgroup
  {% seems a curly-brace-nested argument is to be caught:
    \catcode`\}=2    % <- give closing curly brace the usual catcode also.
    \UD@collectverbarg{#1}{#2}{#3}{}%
  }{% seems an argument with verbatim-syntax-delimiter is to be caught:
    \do\{% <- give opening curly brace the verbatim-catcode again.
    \UD@collectverbarg{#1}{#2}{#3}%
  }%
}%
\newcommand\UD@collectverbarg[4]{%
  \do\ %   <- Now that \UD@collectverbarg has the delimiter or
  \do\^^I%    emptiness in its 4th arg, give space and horizontal tab
         %    the verbatim-catcode again.
  \do\^^M% <- Give the carriage-return-character the verbatim-catcode.
  \long\def\@tempb##1#4{%
    %\edef\@tempb{##1}%
    \def\@tempb{##1}%
    \@onelevel@sanitize\@tempb % <- Turn characters into their "12/other"-pendants.
                               %    This may be important with things like the 
                               %    inputenc-package which may make characters 
                               %    active/which give them catcode 13(active).
    \expandafter\UDEndlreplace\expandafter{\@tempb}{#1}{\def\@tempb}% <- this starts 
                               %    the loop for replacing endline-characters.
    \expandafter\UD@@collectverbarg\expandafter{\@tempb}{#2}{#3}% <- this "spits 
                               %    out the result.
  }%
  \@tempb
}%
\newcommand\UD@@collectverbarg[3]{%
  \endgroup
  #2{#3{#1}}%
}%
%%<---------------- End of code for \UDcollectverbarg ----------------->

% The integer-parameter \newlinechar usually has the value 10.
% This means if at the time of writing to text-file (La)TeX encounters a
% character whose code-point's number in (La)TeX's internal character-encoding
% (which either is ASCII or is UTF-8)  is 10, it will not write that character
% but will write a linebreak. 10 denotes the Line Feed-character and using
% (La)TeX's ^^-notation you can also write it as ^^J.
\newcommand{\cf}[1]{%
  \UDcollectverbarg{^^J}{\UD@firstofone}{\innercf{#1}}%
}%
\begingroup
\newcommand\innercf[2]{%
  \endgroup
  \newcommand\innercf[2]{%
    \scantokens{%
      #1{prefix-##1.tex}^^J%
      factored-complex-processing-of{##2}^^J%
      #2%
    }%
  }%
}%
\UDcollectverbarg{^^J}{%
  \UDcollectverbarg{^^J}{\UD@firstofone}%
}{\innercf}|\begin{filecontents}||\end{filecontents}|%


\cf{suffix1}{ somefirststuff\string#\LaTeX}%

\begin{filecontents}{prefix-suffix2.tex}
factored-complex-processing-of{ somenextstuff\string#\LaTeX}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\noindent prefix-suffix1.tex is:

\verbatiminput{prefix-suffix1.tex}

\noindent\hrulefill\null

\noindent prefix-suffix2.tex is:

\verbatiminput{prefix-suffix2.tex}

\noindent\hrulefill\null

\noindent\verb|\input{prefix-suffix1.tex}| yields:

\noindent\input{prefix-suffix1.tex}

\noindent\hrulefill\null

\noindent\verb|\input{prefix-suffix2.tex}| yields:

\noindent\input{prefix-suffix2.tex}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want the stuff in `\cf`s second argument to be fully evaluated/expanded before writing it to file, you can probably apply `\protected@edef` and `\@onelevel@sanitize`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\newcommand\exchange[2]{#2#1}

% The integer-parameter \newlinechar usually has the value 10.
% This means if at the time of writing to text-file (La)TeX encounters a
% character whose code-point's number in (La)TeX's internal character-encoding
% (which either is ASCII or is UTF-8)  is 10, it will not write that character
% but will write a linebreak. 10 denotes the Line Feed-character and using
% (La)TeX's ^^-notation you can also write it as ^^J.

\newenvironment{localscope}{}{}%

\begingroup
\makeatletter
\newcommand\cf[2]{%
  \endgroup
  \newcommand{\cf}[2]{%
    \begin{localscope}%
    \protected@edef\UD@tempa{##2}%
    \@onelevel@sanitize\UD@tempa
    \expandafter\exchange\expandafter{%
    \expandafter\scantokens\expandafter{%
      \romannumeral0\expandafter\exchange\expandafter{\expandafter{\UD@tempa}}{ %
      #1{prefix-##1.tex}^^J%
      factored-complex-processing-of}^^J%
      #2%
    }}%
    {\end{localscope}}%
  }%
}%
\expandafter\exchange\expandafter{\expandafter{\string\end{filecontents}}}%
{\expandafter\cf\expandafter{\string\begin{filecontents}}}%

\newcommand\firststage{\secondstage}
\newcommand\secondstage{\thirdstage}
\newcommand\thirdstage{Expanded. \LaTeX}

\cf{suffix1}{ somefirststuff \firststage}%

\begin{filecontents}{prefix-suffix2.tex}
factored-complex-processing-of{ somenextstuff \firststage}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\noindent prefix-suffix1.tex is:

\verbatiminput{prefix-suffix1.tex}

\noindent\hrulefill\null

\noindent prefix-suffix2.tex is:

\verbatiminput{prefix-suffix2.tex}

\noindent\hrulefill\null

\noindent\verb|\input{prefix-suffix1.tex}| yields:

\noindent\input{prefix-suffix1.tex}

\noindent\hrulefill\null

\noindent\verb|\input{prefix-suffix2.tex}| yields:

\noindent\input{prefix-suffix2.tex}

\end{document}
```

[image]